# How to change vscode's color theme using the the CLI? (`code` command)

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ide, command-line-interface

Is it even possible to change the colour theme using the CLI? I went through the [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line) but could not find anything that matches this requirement.

I am working on a personal project where I am adding a cron job to switch the theme of my computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to change settings using the `code` command, but instead you could use `sed` to edit [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations) like so:

```
sed -i -e 's/"workbench.colorTheme": ".*"/"workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark"/g' "$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json"
```

- `"workbench.colorTheme": ".*"` is the regular expression (regex) to replace.
- `"workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark"` is the replacement string. Change `Visual Studio Dark` to your desired theme.
- `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json` is the path to your `settings.json`

Answer (score -2):

Here is a good APP to learn and understand unix and linux in better way.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kanha.unixlinuxpocketbook